# Django 1.11 querysets: Get all objects (model instances) of a relationship set

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm, django-1.11

If have a model for companies. These companies have an attribute `employment_set`, because workers are assigned to companies via the employment relation. How can I query all employees for a given company?
The model for the employements look like this:

```
class Employment(
    SoftDeletableModel,
    TimeStampedModel,
    models.Model
):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    employee = models.ForeignKey(UserWorkerProfile)
    employed_by = models.ForeignKey(UserOwnerProfile)
```

I tried using `company.employment_set.values("employee")`, but this returns a strange activatorquery set. Is there a way to return the normal queryset? Or is `values()` already the correct method?

Edit: To eloborate a little more: I want to end up with a queryset containing all the UserWorkerprofile model instances.

In the documentation for `values()` it says:

> Returns a QuerySet that returns dictionaries, rather than model instances, when used as an iterable.

and I want exactly a queryset of model instances.

Comment: Well like you say, the `employment_set`. This is a manager, so you can for example write `some_company.employment_set.all()` to obtain all the `Employment`s. This is like every QuerySet: you can `.filter(..)`, etc.

Comment: @willem-van-onsem Yeah but then I have all the employment model instances. I elaborated the question further. I want to end up with a queryset of all the employees, not the employments.

Comment: aah, that's `UserWorkerProfile.objects.filter(employment__company=some_company)`.

Comment: @willem-van-onsem Thank you this already helps a lot! Is this the only way to do it in reverse so? From the company, more like I described it above?

Comment: Not as far as I know, you can not query a relation of an object manager as far as I know (afaik, there does *not* exists something like `some_company.employment_set.userworkerprofile_set`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment, you want *all* `UserWorkerProfile`s that have *a* (there can be zero, one or more) related `Employment` instances an `Employment` instance that has as `Company` (every `Employment` has *exactly* one `company`), a given company.

We can query such `UserWorkingProfile`s with the following query:

```
UserWorkingProfile.objects.filter(employment__company=some_comany)
```

So this queryset will return *all* `UserWorkingProfile`s for which there exists an `Employment` instance that links to the given company `some_company` and that `UserWorkingProfile`.

In Django one uses two consecutive underscores to look "through" a relation (this can be used in *bidirectionally*, note that two consecitive underscores are used for other things than looking through relations).

We thus wrote a query that looks, more or less like:

```
SELECT `userworkingprofile`.*
FROM `userworkingprofile`
JOIN `employment` ON `employment`.`employee_id` = `userworkingprofile`.`id`
WHERE `employment`.`company_id` = 123
```

With `123` in reality the `pk` of `some_company`.

Note that it is possible that the *same* `UserWorkingProfile` occurs *multiple* times in this queryset, if the employee has worked several times for `some_company`.

If you want every `UserWorkingProfile` to occur at most *once*, you should add `.distinct()` to it:

```
UserWorkingProfile.objects.filter(employment__company=some_comany).distinct()
```

Although Django indeed defines a object manager named `employment_set` on a `Company` instance, as far as I know you can not "combine" two such managers (so `some_company.employment_set.employee` will *not* work).

Comment: Then I described it falsely. I want them to have at least one related Employement instance :)

Comment: @J.Hesters: well this is indeed what the query does. But due to the fact of the `JOIN`ing, the same `UserWorkingProfile` can occur multiple times, if that person worked *several* times fro that company.